# Body contents overlapping bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am building a site with bootstrap. The navbar is not acting like a static element relative to the rest of the body elements. In some cases the elements in the body will get pushed up and cover the navbar. This specifically happens if I zoom into the page and everything in the body covers the navbar making the links unclickable. [Here is one example of what is occuring.](https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/1128401K0x3F101Z3Z2j/issue%20with%20navbar.27132m3M0z11.png) I have tried a few things: I've done added the bootstrap class .navbar-static-top to the navbar but that had no effect. I've read multiple accounts of the navbar covering up the body but the reverse is happening to me. I also considered changing the z-index but then the page contents will just get pushed up behind the navbar. I have looked at multiple questions on Stack but none of them solved it for me. HTML:

```html
<html lang="EN">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/stylesheets/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        ...various links...
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS for .navbar and .navbar-custom:

```css
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-custom {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}
```

My impulse was to change the position of .navbar to `static` instead of ``relative but that also didn't do it. How can I get the navbar to behave like a regular static element and not get overlapped by the rest of the page contents?

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/joelbitar1986/ny-freegan-forum)

Comment: your question is a little unclear. your navbar is being covered when it shouldn't be? do you have a working example you can share?

Comment: So, a little embarassing but I figured out what was causing this. Some CSS that I sneaked into my stylesheet a few days ago causing the div to automatically center vertically, which is not friendly to responsive design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had some code that was causing the div to be vertically centered. This was causing the navbar to be covered by the div when zooming in.

The culprit was some CSS that I was calling on the div in question:

```css
.vert-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```